# Standard way of joining two Data.Texts without `mappend`

Tags: haskell

I hear that `Data.Text` is going to replace `String`s in future Haskell versions. One issue I have with this is that `(++)` is defined for lists only. To concatenate two `Text`s, I need to use

```
text1 `mappend` text2
```

Which gets verbose quickly. Ideally I'd like to be able to use `++` on these `Text`s, but if not, what is another alternative? I could define my own infix operator, but I'd like a standard way of doing this.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

From GHC 7.4 (not sure which point version) there is a predefined `<>` operator that works the same as `mappend`. So you'll be able to say

```
text1 <> text2
```

So that's the "standard" infix operator, but it's not available everywhere yet.

Comment: That is a poorly named operator. `<>` has the semantics of "not equal to". It would have been nicer to generalize `++` to work on all Monoids.

Comment: <> was chosen because it was already in use by the pretty printing libraries with monoidal semantics, and its the least obtrusive option that doesn't break existing code, or have odd biases. Generalizing (++) on the other hand, can't be done in a way that makes for nice pretty printing libraries due to the precedence level, and it used to have yet another meaning before haskell 98, when it was used for what we call mplus now. If we avoided things with meanings in other languages we'd have no operators left! The operators <<, >>, --, !, %, : etc. all have other semantics in other languages too.

Comment: Strange, I'm trying to use it but getting `Not in scope: ‘<>’`. GHC 7.10.3

Comment: To answer my question `Data.Monoid (<>)` needs to be imported

Answer (score 1):

Just use `mconcat` for all type of monoids. You don't need to import anything, and code looks much cleaner with it.

example:

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}

import           Data.Text

table :: Text
table = "user"

fields :: [Text]
fields = ["id","nickname","password","date","posts","comments"]

insertquery :: Text -> [Text] -> Text
insertquery table fields = mconcat
  ["insert into ",table," (",names,") values (",vals,");"]
  where
    names = insertcomma fields
    vals  = insertcomma [singleton '?' | _ <- fields]
    insertcomma = intercalate (singleton ',')
```

and the result it gives:

> λ> insertquery table fields
>
> "insert into user (id,nickname,password,date,posts,comments) values
>   (?,?,?,?,?,?);"

Comment: I'm not sure I agree `mconcat [...]` is better than `<>`, especially when there are only two or three values to combine. But it's definitely an option worth considering for larger concatenations like your example.