# Not in scope: ‘<>’ for Data.Text

Tags: haskell

I'm trying to join two Data.Text using `<>` operator, but when I compile I see the following error:

```
Not in scope: ‘<>’
    Perhaps you meant one of these:
      ‘<*>’ (imported from Prelude), ‘>>’ (imported from Prelude),
      ‘<=’ (imported from Prelude)
```

I use GHC 7.10.3, but according to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9963250/793874) it was added long ago.

Probably there is already answer to that question, but it's very hard to find it on StackOverflow due to `<>` symbols.

Could you please help?

Comment: `import Data.Monoid ((<>))`

Comment: Welcome to monoids, enjoy your stay.  Watch out for the functors.

Comment: Oh, shame on me... @Michael I think it's valid answer for invalid question... make it answer I will accept it. or should I remove question?

Comment: OK, there is nothing to add to answer by @leftaroundabout

Comment: By the way, when searching for symbols you can use [SymbolHound](http://symbolhound.com).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Whenever the compiler complains that some function isn't in scope, there's a good chance that you've just forgotten to import it. Your first stop at such an occasion should be Hayoo, which [will readily tell you](http://hayoo.fh-wedel.de/?query=%3C%3E) that `<>` is defined in the module `Data.Monoid` from the `base` library<sup>†</sup>. So you just need to

```
import Data.Monoid ((<>))
```

on top of your module. Actually that's such a common module that I'd pretty much always import it, just as

```
import Data.Monoid
```

---

<sup>†</sup><sub>If something *isn't* in `base`, you may also need to install the package it is in / add it as a dependency to the `.cabal` file.</sub>

Comment: Thanks! did not know about Hayoo... Tried [query on Hoogle](https://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=%3C%3E) but results where irrelevant. Does anybody know why?

Comment: That's strange indeed, I would have thought Hoogle would also give the correct location.

Comment: The stackage version of Hoogle [does find it](https://www.stackage.org/lts-6.2/hoogle?q=%3C%3E). No idea why haskell.org/hoogle doesn't.